# Multiple PJAX Requests

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, pjax

I am trying to update 2 separate divs with PJAX. My PJAX fails and only the second one is loaded. Here's an example:

```
<div id="content-1"></div>
<div id="content-2"></div>

<button onclick="
$.pjax({
url: 'content-1.php',
container: '#content-1',
push: false
});

$.pjax({
url: 'content-2.php',
container: '#content-2',
push: false
});
"></button>
```

The problem is that the 2 pjax requests can't run simultaneously and the second one overlaps the first one, so only the second one (the one with id="content-2") is updated.
Push is set to false for a reason, I don't need the url to be pushed in that particular case, but I need it for other parts of the site.

Comment: are you 100% sure the first pjax works? if you remove the second pjax call does it change #content-1?

Comment: I think you're supposed to use ordinary ajax `load()` if you don't want to update the page URL.

Comment: @popnoodles Yes, I am 100% sure that when the second PJAX is removed, the first one works.

Comment: @SeanHogan What about caching? The PJAX have caching, and AJAX don't? I need caching for static loaded pagelets on the site. Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends. You could just leave content in the DOM and hide / show as appropriate. Or manage your own session cache. Or set HTTP cache headers and let the browser take care of caching.

Comment: The idea is to make facebook-like caching for pagelets generated with PJAX/AJAX. I know they are using memcached, but I don't know if it could be implemented in a system, which uses PJAX/AJAX. What alternatives for caching information do I have when speaking of PJAX-ing/AJAX-ing + Cache. Sorry if the question seems stupid, I'm not a newbie in web development, but I don't have that much experience with caching. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL address does not need to be changed, AJAX should be used instead of PJAX. PJAX and AJAX do the same thing - update only a certain part of the HTML content, without reloading the whole page. However, PJAX changes the URL address in the address bar, so it should only be used in that particular way.

A good example of the usage of PJAX and AJAX is a simple gallery. If the page has to be changed, it is better to use PJAX, so that it could change the URL in the address bar, adding a GET parameter for the page. But it is more appropriate to use AJAX for getting additional information for a clicked image in a pop-up.

Comment: I don't understand. do you have a split personality or something? answering to yourself in this manner..

Comment: A figured it out myself, so I wrote an answer. Maybe you are the one who doesn't know how Stackoverflow works :)

Comment: I know how, I also answers my own questions, but not like i'm talking to myself :) I keep it technical. Btw, Sofia rocks!

Comment: @vsync When I'm using "you", I'm referring to the one reading the answer. It's more friendly to him/her (just sounds nicer).

Comment: in technical programming, it's always preferred to never address a person, for example your sentence `If you do not need to change the URL address` should be: `If the URL address needs to updated`..it's how docs are written in computer science :) documentation never refers to some imaginary person

Comment: Thanks @vsync I eddited the answer - you can check it.

Comment: This was the explanation I needed, TY OP.